# I can't add several TextViews in a Layout from method

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to create a menu list from json data in a LinearLayout using the follwing code:

```
            LinearLayout myLayout   = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.info);    

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("store");
                textView = new TextView(context);           
                textView.setText(jsonObj.getString("name"));
                textView.setId(jsonObj.getInt("id"));
                myLayout.addView(textView);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
```

It works, but only until the third record, after that all the text views are not shown.
I think there may be a limit or something that doesn't allow me to add more textviews.

Any idea?

Comment: are you sure that your jsonArray.length() is bigger than 3?

Comment: Are you saying that when it adds the fourth view (i == 3), the layout becomes blank? What happens if you skip i == 3 and try i == 4?   And, what is your xml for the layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think first you should make your layout linear and vertical. Do its `orientation vertical` in the `xml`.

[android:orientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3aorientation)

Answer (score 0):

You're better of using a `ListView` and `ArrayAdapter`, as far as I know `addView` is no longer supported, and throws an exception when used in recent versions of Android.

[This](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) is a great tutorial on the subject.